# Porting DES-EDE3-CBC from PHP to Ruby gives different results

Tags: php, ruby, openssl

I'm trying to port a PHP library to ruby and the encrypt/decrypt function is not giving the same result:

I'm trying to convert this method:

```php
function encrypt_3DES($message, $key){
  $l = ceil(strlen($message) / 8) * 8;
  $padded_message = $message . str_repeat("\0", $l - strlen($message));
  $iv = "\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0";
  return substr(openssl_encrypt($padded_message, 'des-ede3-cbc', $key, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, $iv), 0, $l);
}
```

Into this:

```rb
def encrypt_3DES(message, key)
  cipher = OpenSSL::Cipher.new('DES-EDE3-CBC')
  cipher.encrypt
  cipher.key = key
  cipher.iv = "\0" * 8
  output = cipher.update(message) + cipher.final
  output 
end
```

This is giving me some problems:

1. The original key is 24 bytes long, and ruby raises an exception

   - The original key: `Base64.decode64('sq7HjrUOBfKmC576ILgskD5srU870gJ7')`
   - in ruby raises: `ArgumentError (key must be 16 bytes)`
   - in php it works with any key length
2. Using the same message and key that ruby accepts, the php output is different

   - message: `message1`
   - key: `1234567890123456`
   - php output in base64: `uJxPvodsbLs=`
   - ruby output in base64: `K8v3K/w4pS7R2DHXr0UHbQ==`

What am I doing wrong?

I'm using  PHP 7.3.11 and ruby 2.6.5p114

Comment: `des-ede3-cbc` vs. `des-ede-cbc`?

Comment: @cremno you were spot on. Can you submit a response so I can accept it? as you were the first to point it out, I feel bad giving the accept to another person

Answer (score 1):

`des-ede-cbc` (which you use in Ruby) is a slightly different variant of tripple-des than `des-ede3-cbc` which you use in PHP. With `des-ede-cbc`, you would use the same key for the two encryption phases (which explains why you only need two keys, i.e. 2 * 8 = 16 bytes) while with `des-ede3-cbc`, you use three keys, hence 3 * 8 = 24 bytes.

If you use the correct algorithm, you get the same output from OpenSSL (but see below).

```php
function encrypt_3DES($message, $key){
  $l = ceil(strlen($message) / 8) * 8;
  $padded_message = $message . str_repeat("\0", $l - strlen($message));
  $iv = "\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0";
  return substr(openssl_encrypt($padded_message, 'des-ede3-cbc', $key, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, $iv), 0, $l);
}

echo base64_encode(encrypt_3DES('message1', base64_decode('sq7HjrUOBfKmC576ILgskD5srU870gJ7')));
# => "OO4olPtGedE="
```

```rb
def encrypt_3DES(message, key)
  cipher = OpenSSL::Cipher.new('des-ede3-cbc')
  cipher.encrypt
  cipher.key = key
  cipher.iv = "\0" * 8
  output = cipher.update(message)
  output 
end

Base64.encode64 encrypt_3DES('message1', Base64.decode64('sq7HjrUOBfKmC576ILgskD5srU870gJ7'))
# => "OO4olPtGedE6qq1lHRAtgQ==\n"
```

You can see that the prefix is the same in both instances.  The only difference is that in your PHP implementation, you are not generating (resp. removing) the final chunk which is however necessary to actually decrypt the data. By removing the `substr` logic from your PHP version, you should get the correct encrypted data in both cases.

With that being said, please take into consideration that 3DES is an incredibly outdated and (for most current applications) insecure algorithm. If you intend to use this outside of any toy application (that is: if you intend to ship production code with this, you should use a more modern algorithm. A good, secure and well-maintained option is to use libsodium's secretbox. Since PHP 7.2, this is shipped with PHP itself, older versions can use a PECL package. There is [some documentation](https://paragonie.com/book/pecl-libsodium/read/04-secretkey-crypto.md) available on how to use this.

In Ruby, you can use the [rbnacl](https://github.com/RubyCrypto/rbnacl) gem which also uses libsodium under the hood and brings the same capabilities.